# How can I group data by days that have passed and amount in PostgreSQL? (<30, 31-60, 61-90, 91+)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, graph

I am new to PostgreSQL and writing SQL statements in general, so I'm looking for a bit of help!

All of my data is on a single table (accounts), and I need to pull in a dollar value (recovery_amount), two dates (appeal_date and recovery_date), and finally group the data by the difference of the appeal_date and recovery_date to see the total recovery_amount as the days mature.

Something like (recovery_date - appeal_date) in days = recovery_amount total in <30 Days, recovery_amount total in 31-60 Days, recovery_amount total in 61-90 Days, and recovery_amount total over 90 days.

I'm attempting statements like:

```
SELECT recovery_amount AS "Total"
CASE
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 90 then 90
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 60 then 60
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 30 then 30
  else 0
END GROUP
FROM accounts
GROUP BY "Total"
```

The end goal is to use this data on a bar graph (if that helps you to visualize the reasoning.)

This is obviously way off, as I have been trying lots of variations to no avail.

Any help you guys/gals can give is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not that far...

```
SELECT  
sum(recoveryTotal) as TotalAmount, --if you want the overall total
sum (case when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 90 then recoveryTotal else 0 end) as total90,
sum (case when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 60 then recoveryTotal else 0 end)as total60,
sum (case when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 30 then recoveryTotyl else 0 end) as total30
FROM accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data in 3 columns.

```
SELECT count(*) NoOfAccts, sum(recovery_amount) AS "GroupTotal"
CASE
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 90 then 90
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 60 then 60
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 30 then 30
  else 0
END GROUP
FROM accounts
GROUP BY CASE
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 90 then 90
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 60 then 60
  when (appeal_date - payment_date) >= 30 then 30
  else 0
END
```

Would result in something like

```
NoOfAccts   GroupTotal    Group
22          3754.48       90
96          24834.83      60
123         38348.48      30
9999        1824389.83    0
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is conditional aggregation (see Raphaël's answer).

If you don't really need this as separate columns, you can make this a bit more dynamic (=easier to maintain) if you use a list of ranges. As you are planning to use that for a report, that should be OK

```
with limits (range) as (
  values 
    (int4range(0,30,'[)')),
    (int4range(30,60,'[)')),
    (int4range(60,90,'[)')),
    (int4range(90,null,'[)'))
)
select l.range as day_range,
       sum(coalesce(recovery_amount,0)) as total
from limits l
  left join accounts ac
    on (ac.appeal_date - ac.payment_date) <@ l.range
group by range
order by range;
```

Example: http://rextester.com/UYDOV15732

Now if you want a new range, you just add that to the list of ranges without changing the actual query. You could even automatically generate equally sized ranges from the data that automatically adjust to the data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use DATE_PART to find the difference in days, http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff.

So if I'm understanding correctly that you're trying to group the total recovery amount by the date difference, something like:

```
    SELECT CASE DATE_PART('day', appeal_date - payment_date)
            WHEN <= 30 THEN '<=30'
            WHEN BETWEEN 31 and 60 THEN '31-60'
            WHEN BETWEEN 61 and 90 THEN '61-90'
            WHEN > 90 THEN '>90'
            ELSE 0
        END as 'DateRange',
        SUM(recovery_amount) AS "Total"
    FROM accounts
    GROUP BY CASE DATE_PART('day', appeal_date - payment_date)
            WHEN <= 30 THEN '<=30'
            WHEN BETWEEN 31 and 60 THEN '31-60'
            WHEN BETWEEN 61 and 90 THEN '61-90'
            WHEN > 90 THEN '>90'
            ELSE 0
        END
```

Comment: I definitely researched that link...

Thanks for the help!